# Using .detach() removes events?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a DIV with alot of content inside it which I use detach() and after() to place it somewhere else in the document.

Prior to this, I use .bind() to put some click events on checkboxes inside the DIV.

This seems to work fine.

When I am finished with the DIV, I put it back into it's original location. When I use the same method of .detach() and after() again though, my click handlers appear to be gone.

Is this normal behavior for detach()? Is there a proper way to preserve events?

For inquiring minds, my DIV contains a form with some validation functions on the checkboxes using the bound click. The detach is used to place the form in a modal dialog and place it back into a hidden DIV if the user closes the dialog. When the user opens the dialog with the form again is when I experience the loss of my click events.

Comment: jQuery `detach()` should mantain event handlers and data associated to the elements: could you reproduce the issue in a reduced fiddle?

Comment: No, `detach` will preserve event handlers, have a look at the docs. If you experience problems, it must be something else.

Comment: Question: is bind("click") considered jQuery data? I'm just wondering if I even need to use detach() and I can just use remove() instead.

Comment: @Matthew, yes it is: look at live example in http://api.jquery.com/detach/ , click handler always work.

Comment: Posting the relevant parts of the jQuery and HTML may help.

Comment: Working on a reduced fiddle as Fabrizio suggested

Comment: I can't reproduce it with a simple fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n874q/1/ It must be some deeper issue. Note: in my actual code I am also passing a closure variable to my bound click event so this is what I will check on next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, using .detach() does not remove events.

I couldn't seem to reproduce this even using a fiddle that is closer to my actual code

http://jsfiddle.net/n874q/5/

My problem was that my click function was failing (silently) on a jQuery array of checkboxes passed in when the function was bound.

I did solve the problem by instead, finding the checkboxes via selector within the function instead of passing the array to the function.

Thanks.